# Knockout not posting to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I've looked through plenty of examples and tried many different ways and I've not been able to get my Knockout to post to my controller using MVC 4. Any ideas what the issue is? I'm new to MVC and Knockout so explanations would be helpful.

```
**knockout.js**
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="~/MyJS/AddTeamMember.js"></script> -->
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var initialData = [
    {
        name: "", email: "", phone: "", dept: ""
    }
    ];
    var ContactsModel = function (contacts) {
        var self = this;
        self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function (contact) {
            return { name: contact.name, email: contact.email, phone: contact.phone, dept: contact.dept };
        }));


        self.addContact = function () {
            self.contacts.push({
                name: "",
                email: "",
                phone: "",
                dept: ""
            });
        };

        self.removeContact = function (contact) {
            self.contacts.remove(contact);
        };   

        self.save = function () {
            self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
            var jsonString = ko.mapping.toJSON(self.contacts);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Register", "Register")',
                data: jsonString,            
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json'   
        });
    };



    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("") 
};
</script>
```

**View Code:**

```
<div class='memInfoForm'> 

                <h2>Team Members</h2>
                <div id='contactsList'> 
                    <table class='contactsEditor'>                
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Dept</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: contacts">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input data-bind='value: name' />
                                    <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeContact'>Delete</a></div>
                                </td>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: email' /></td>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: phone' /></td>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: dept' /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <p>
                    <button data-bind='click: addContact'>Add a Member</button>
                   <button data-bind='click: save, enable: contacts().length > 0' id="saveMembers">Save Member List</button> 
                </p>
```

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost]       
        public ActionResult Register(ContactsModel model)
        {

            ...

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Note - I left out the processing in the controller for this example. My problem is I cannot get the form to even post at all to my controller.

Comment: What have you tried? Is there an error in your browser console when you do click the save button? Is the `save` function being called at all? Is there an AJAX request going out? Posting your entire application code including the Excel manipulation code (WTF?) and hoping the community will pinpoint your issue is not a great idea. Narrow it down to a specific issue and then we could help.

Comment: Yes, the saved function is being called. It first populates the textarea with the json string and that is working however the post isn't happening. I have tried with both hard coding the controller and using the razor helper (I pulled from an example) but noted from Avish that the helper wouldn't work I've returned the url to being hard coded. I do not get an error in the browser because nothing happens at all.

Comment: I also tried a poor workaround of populating the textarea with the json string while the textarea was in a <form> tag. The post will then happen but will send a null instead of the text inside the textarea. Not the solution I wanted; I just playing around.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you're trying to use a Razor helper (`@Url.Action`) inside a static JS file, which won't work. Razor code only work in Razor views (`.cshtml`).

In a static JS file, you'll need to either hard-code the URL, or get it from somewhere else. If you want to use the routing table via `@Url.Action`, one option is to render it into a data-attribute in your view, and read it from there in your Javascript file.

Start by replacing the `@Url.Action` part with a hard-coded path like `'/register/register'` and work from there.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I did attempt the hard coded address before and it did not post. I understand why a razor helper wouldn't work.

Comment: Once I was able to get the post to work I was able to use the razor helper inside the js script. Just fyi.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what was wrong and wanted to note it in case anyone else goofed. I had the

```
<body onload="ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));">
```

to apply the bindings. I moved it to

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
    });
```

It would then post to my controller. Also, the "@Url.Action("Register", "Register")" did work. Thank you everyone for your help.